# Getting error when trying to share code between two Vue and Vite apps in the same repository

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I'm trying to share code between two apps in the same repository with the goal of avoiding having to create a private npm module to share code. I thought with Vite we could have a directory structure something like

```
 - common
 - webapp1
 - webapp2
```

and then use relative paths to import shared code. This worked fine for simple cases where it was just javascript/typescript or a view component. However, once I started moving over coder that uses other public npm packages (axios) it worked at first but if you delete the node modules folder which I assume deletes the npm cache it started breaking with the error below.

```
  VITE v3.0.4  ready in 428 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:8081/
  ➜  Network: http://192.168.254.3:8081/
Failed to resolve import "axios" from "../common/infrastructure/http/index.js". Does the file exist?
3:56:43 PM [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "axios" from "../common/infrastructure/http/index.js". Does the file exist?
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: /Users/ryan/code/analyzer-app/common/infrastructure/http/index.js
  1  |  import axios from "axios";
     |                     ^
  2  |  import * as Sentry from "@sentry/vue";
  3  |  
      at formatError (file:///Users/ryan/code/analyzer-app/webapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-71eb12cb.js:35035:46)
      at TransformContext.error (file:///Users/ryan/code/analyzer-app/webapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-71eb12cb.js:35031:19)
      at normalizeUrl (file:///Users/ryan/code/analyzer-app/webapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-71eb12cb.js:40181:33)
      at async TransformContext.transform (file:///Users/ryan/code/analyzer-app/webapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-71eb12cb.js:40315:47)
      at async Object.transform (file:///Users/ryan/code/analyzer-app/webapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-71eb12cb.js:35284:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///Users/ryan/code/analyzer-app/webapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-71eb12cb.js:39812:29)
```

**Shared Code**

```
// common/infrastructure/http/index.js
import axios from "axios";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/vue";

let handleErrorMessage;
let handleSuccessMessage;

// removed for brevity 

const configure = ({ onErrorMessage, onSuccessMessage} = {}) => {
  handleErrorMessage = onErrorMessage;
  handleSuccessMessage = onSuccessMessage;
}

export default {
// removed for brevity 
    configure
};
```

** Consuming Code **

```
// common/infrastructure/http/index.js

// removed for brevity 

import { configure as configureDoAsync } from "../../common/infrastructure/doAsync";

// removed for brevity 

// Configure doAsync for error and success message handling
configureDoAsync({
    onErrorMessage: message => store.dispatch("toastMessage/notifyError", { message }, { root: true }),
    onSuccessMessage: message => store.dispatch("toastMessage/notifySuccess", { message: message }, { root: true })
});

// removed for brevity
```

Comment: Use `"dependencies": { "bar": "file:../foo/bar" }` in `package.json`. Then, anywhere in the project: `import { stuff } from 'bar'`. Read [local paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths).

Comment: I think this works. I tried something similar but without the `"file:"` text in `package.json` added to `common`. The contents look like: `"dependencies": {"axios": "../webapp1/node_modules/axios" }`